# Maintain Historical table with updates from new data on userID- SQL

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, hive, pyspark, databricks

Considering i have a table that contains historical data (2 years), which has been created after running the following query in spark:

```
temp_result = spark.sql("SELECT gaid,MIN(CASE WHEN upper(event) in ('APP 
ACCESS', 'APP OPENED', 'APP LAUNCHED') THEN date_stamp_ist END) as 
first_app_access_date,MIN(CASE WHEN upper(event) in ('MEDIAREADY', 'MEDIA 
READY') THEN date_stamp_ist END) as first_app_viewed_date FROM df_raw_data 
GROUP BY gaid")
```

The data looks like this:

```
 - --------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|                gaid|first_app_access_date|first_app_viewed_date|
+--------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|00001C8A-2326-469...|           2018-09-03|           2018-09-03|
|00021783-C199-4FE...|           2018-09-01|           2018-09-01|
|0003432f-6e30-4c0...|           2018-09-04|           2018-09-04|
|000662ae-2b9b-468...|           2018-09-02|           2018-09-02|
|0009ac47-c7a2-4b6...|           2018-09-01|           2018-09-01|
|000c245b-58b1-492...|           2018-09-03|           2018-09-03|
|000f327b-56dc-4c8...|           2018-09-01|           2018-09-01|
|001149cb-f51c-4c0...|           2018-09-01|           2018-09-01|
|0013ad65-2843-4d3...|           2018-09-04|           2018-09-04|
|0015170a-fda1-41c...|           2018-09-05|           2018-09-05|
|001cf486-035a-43e...|           2018-09-04|           2018-09-04|
|001f2ecf-bf0f-47d...|           2018-09-03|                 null|
|002053e8-2cf6-43f...|           2018-09-04|           2018-09-04|
|002303e0-5aa4-4eb...|           2018-09-01|           2018-09-01|
|0025f65c-5818-4c3...|           2018-09-01|                 null|
|002807db-b0a2-487...|           2018-09-03|           2018-09-03|
|002befcc-cdfd-463...|           2018-09-01|           2018-09-01|
|00364046-b022-497...|           2018-09-02|                 null|
```

What i am trying to do is to find the first app access and first app view for a user(gaid).

Now, when i run this against the new months data, i want to:

1. Verify if the gaid coming in new data is present in historical data or not.
2. If it's present, that means we already have the first app access and we do nothing.
3. If the gaid is not present in historical data(that means its a new id), it should run the same query to calculate the first app access and first app view and insert it into the historical data.
4. For a particular gaid, first app access has to be present and first app view can be null as a person could have access but viewed something later.
5. For such entries, it should update the first app view in the historical data.

I am having a hard time executing this. Help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually a very big project, but I can give you some suggestions from my own experience.

For 1/2/3, I think that you should use RoaringBitmap to store your gaids, which means that you need to convert gaid to a int number. However, you need to pay attention to the conversion, because you can't do it in a simple way like String.hashCode(), which may introduce a int conflict in a RoaringBitmap.

For 4/5, it's obviously not a typical scenario on append-only file system like HDFS. In order to achieve this, you have to take advantage of some external distributed database or frameworks like HBase, RocksDB and Alluxio.